# Flickr API: Programmatically Accessible Documentation

Tags: flickr

I'd like to be able to programmatically query the API. For example, I'd like to know what arguments are required/optional, and their types, for a given method. The info must be somewhere because it is used by [the Explorer](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/?method=flickr.photos.search), but I didn't see a way to access it, and I struck out searching because the terms are so generic (e.g. 'metadata' brings up tons of hits on EXIF).

I'm asking because I'm writing a wrapper and want to provide interactive help without having to scrape the web documentation.

Comment: What is "the Explorer"?

Comment: Possibly you mean [this](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search) for the Explorer? I am still not quite sure what your question is. Are you asking how you can query their API programatically? All of the documentation is [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/).

Comment: @Thilo, yes that explorer. I added the link to the question.

Comment: @yiati, yes I'm asking how to query the API programmatically. I want to have an interactive wrapper that avoids having to scrape the web documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool! They have exactly what I wanted...

From https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.reflection.getMethodInfo.html :

> Example Response
>
> ```
> <method name="flickr.fakeMethod" needslogin="1">
>   <description>A fake method</description>
>   <response>xml-response-example</response>
>   <explanation>explanation of example response</explanation>
>   <arguments>
>     <argument name="api_key" optional="0">
>           You API application key.</argument>
>     <argument name="color" optional="1">
>           Your favorite color.</argument>
>   </arguments>
>   <errors>
>     <error code="1" message="Photo not found">
>           Full explanation...</error>
>     <error code="100" message="Invalid API Key">
>           Full explanation...</error>
>   </errors>
> </method>
> ```

Comment: Cool, I have never seen a reflective api method. Looks like that will work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, Flickr does not provide what you are looking for.

What you are describing is an introspective API, and Flickr does not currently provide that. Introspection is an option for API providers, and as stated the Facebook Graph API does have minor support for this with the metadata field. A good example of a framework to help create introspective APIs is [sandman](http://sandman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using_sandman.html#automatic-introspection), but most companies tend to do one/two of the two popular options for updating APIs.

- Announce any changes to their API before making them
- Write their own official client wrapper in x many languages

Flickr does not have any official client wrappers, but they do link to unofficial client wrappers on [their API page](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/).

Since you are looking to build and maintain your own non-official Flickr client wrapper, and Flickr does not provide an introspective API, you are left with the first option of reading announcements to API changes.

These exist through their [changelog blog](https://www.flickr.com/services/developer/changelog/), as well as through their [Flickr API Twitter account](https://twitter.com/flickrAPI). Luckily these events should not happen often so it should not be much of an issue. An additional resource you could use as an extra layer of defense for API updates is a continuous integration service such as [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) to make sure API calls with your wrapper are working as expected.

Your main concern does seem to be the initial generation of your client API wrapper which will inevitably require some manual labor without a introspective API on Flickrs end (but hey that the whole point of writing the wrapper right, so that other people don't have to do the manual labor :D). Depending on the language you are working with to create a client wrapper though, there may be some tools to help you automate a portion of the client wrapper.

One example is that many Object Oriented languages have tools to help parse JSON and convert it into Models for the corresponding language such as [Java](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), [C#](http://json2csharp.com/), [Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/warlock), [More Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema), etc.

Comment: I'm writing my own wrapper and want to avoid implementing either manually by reading or semi-automatically by scraping the web docs

Comment: The Explorer interactive api page was likely made manually by developers at Flickr. Making a program to scrape and parse their online API documentation will likely take just as much effort as copying it over by hand. Plus the fact that the html you would have to parse could change form at any point in time giving you another program you need to maintain.

Comment: yes, that's why I'm trying to avoid scraping! It's surprising that companies don't provide this, which puts a significant burden on programmers to implement wrappers. They could be almost automatic. Facebook provides something like this via the "metadata=1" query, but I don't know how complete it is...

Comment: Flickr does have a [changelog blog](https://www.flickr.com/services/developer/changelog/) as well as an [API Twitter account](https://twitter.com/flickrAPI), both of which are updated about any potential changes to the API. API changes are big, and are usually announced in advance of actual deployment so this should be sufficient. The only other option that API providers have other than feeds are creating their own client API wrappers which Flickr does not seem to do.